# preg_replace <img src=""> by its id="" if it occurs more than 5 times

Tags: php, preg-replace

How do I allow only 5 occurrences using the image id? Let's say I have several images. They all share the same id `id="my_image"`. I want to show 5 images and strip all other images that have the same id.

```
<img id="my_image" src="image_10.gif" alt="12" />
<img id="my_image" src="image_21.gif" alt="12" /> 
<img id="my_image" src="image_33.gif" alt="12" />
<img id="my_image" src="image_4.gif" alt="12" />
<img id="my_image" src="image_56.gif" alt="12" />
<img id="my_image" src="image_60.gif" alt="12" />
<img id="my_image" src="image_19.gif" alt="12" />
...etc.
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Do you really want them to have the same id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)** for matching and `array_slice()` to capture only first five.

```
$images = '<img id="my_image" src="image_10.gif" alt="12" />
<img id="my_image" src="image_21.gif" alt="12" /> 
<img id="my_image" src="image_33.gif" alt="12" />
<img id="my_image" src="image_4.gif" alt="12" />
<img id="my_image" src="image_56.gif" alt="12" />
<img id="my_image" src="image_60.gif" alt="12" />
<img id="my_image" src="image_19.gif" alt="12" />';

preg_match_all('~<img.*\>~', $images, $match);
$match = array_slice($match[0], 0, 5);

print '<pre>';
print_r($match);
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/4oIvH)**

**Note:** Please remember that elements `ID` should be unique. If you do that, fails W3C validation. Also if you write JS by that ID only last one might works. That's why I suggest you to use `class` instead of `ID`.

**Alternative solution:**

Using `class` and `JS` to hide after fifth image:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('my_image')).map((img, key) => key > 4 && (img.style.display = 'none'))
```

```html
<img class="my_image" src="image_10.gif" alt="12" />
<img class="my_image" src="image_21.gif" alt="12" />
<img class="my_image" src="image_33.gif" alt="12" />
<img class="my_image" src="image_4.gif" alt="12" />
<img class="my_image" src="image_56.gif" alt="12" />
<img class="my_image" src="image_60.gif" alt="12" />
<img class="my_image" src="image_19.gif" alt="12" />
```

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Creating the same ids is the bad practice. You should use attribute `class` instead of `id` to mark some elements.

Your code should be like

```
<img class="my_image" src="image_10.gif" alt="12" />
<img class="my_image" src="image_21.gif" alt="12" /> 
<img class="my_image" src="image_33.gif" alt="12" />
<img class="my_image" src="image_4.gif" alt="12" />
```

After this you can easy hide some of elements by `querySelectorAll` js function.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.my_image');

  for (var i = 4; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = 'none'
  }
```

**P.S**
Of course, you can do it with `id` but it is bad.